# How is British tea prepared?

Tags: tea

Do you add any flavor of British breakfast tea?
I need to know how it is prepared; either with or without additional flavor.

Answer (score 5):

*The* British tea? Don't know what that's all about. Anyway...

[English Breakfast Tea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_breakfast_tea) is a mixture of Assam, Ceylon and Kenya teas that is often served with a dash of milk and sugar to taste. The [UK Tea Council](http://www.tea.co.uk/make-a-perfect-brew) discusses their view of the appropriate way to serve each variety at the supplied link. I would think that a great majority of British people take their tea with milk (I don't find the type of tea used palatable without, as it is somewhat bitter and high in tannins, and I don't think many other people do either). When I say a *dash*, what I mean is somewhere in the region of 10% of the volume of the cup, rather than the half and half or thereabouts used in beverages like [chai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masala_chai).

Most British people (in my experience at least) use [teabags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea_bag) which are simply added to the cup and hot water poured on top. However adding several spoonfuls of loose tea to a [teapot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teapot) is not uncommon, as was probably done for millennia wherever tea was drunk, prior to the invention of the teabag.

Comment: I opened the link of UK Tea Council and discovered that all the three kinds, ASSAM, CEYLON and KENYA are prepared with black tea, not green or red.

Comment: @Hanaa yes, in all cases regarding UK and possibly other european countries, if any recipe or process mentions simply "tea" without any  specific details, then it's assumed that it will be black tea and not anything else.

Comment: Allright that means the black tea is dominant .^_^

Comment: That's right @Hanaa. In the UK "tea" without any further qualification would almost always be understood as referring to black tea. Other teas are drunk, but black tea is more traditional. Milk is almost universally used in black tea, sugar use varies.

Comment: I've never thought about it, but *of course* there's a UK Tea Council.

Comment: @logophobe not only that, but there is also a [British Standard for the brewing and tasting of tea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3103)

Answer (score 2):

What I thought of when I read this question was what my mother and grandmother taught me about preparing tea, and the key thing was that the milk has to go into the cup *before* the hot tea so that you do not scald it!

Here is a kind of over-the-top Instructables describing how to [prepare tea correctly](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-proper-cup-of-tea/step5/A-nice-cup-of-tea/)! Step 5 describes getting the tea into the cup.

> Let the tea in the tea pot stand for a few minutes for the tea to brew. The tea cosy will keep the tea warm for a long time. Take your tea cup and saucer (prererably of the finest English bone china) pour a little milk into the cup (milk in first, please!) and then fill with the clear, hot, amber liquid of life! Add sugar to taste and there you are!

Comment: @Hanaa The person who wrote the Instructable is referring to the [color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amber_%28color%29) of the tea.

Comment: I'd just like to add that you'll find the advice "milk in first" actually varies region to region. In the Midlands for example, it's generally far more common for the milk to be added last. This is especially important if you brew in the mug (i.e. without a tea pot); milk, tea bag, then water, results in a distinctively different taste than tea bag, water, left to brew, remove the tea bag, then add milk. Some people prefer the taste, others don't, calling it "teabaggey"! In short - try both variants and see what you think!

Comment: This is the first time i see this color . what known color is amber color near to?

Comment: Brown with a slight orange tint.